# Validation rule for date is greater than?

Tags: validation-rule

Hi I am making a validation rule to check if a billing date end is earlier than the billing date start. My syntax appears to be wrong however.

My current validation formula:

```
DATEVALUE(Billing_Period_Start__c) > DATEVALUE(Billing_Period_End__c)
```

Error: *Incorrect argument type for function 'DATEVALUE()'.*

Fixed by removing DATEVALUE from the validation formula.

Comment: Why are you using `Datevalue` function? just put a simple comparison if both fields are date or datetime.

Comment: What are the field value type? are your fields, `Billing_Period_Start__c` and `Billing_Period_End__c` of type date?

Comment: They are both dates. I fixed the problem, I just removed datevalue from the validation rule.

Comment: @Mahmood please post as answer to close the issue out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your fields `Billing_Period_Start__c` and `Billing_Period_End__c` are of type [**`Date`**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5), hence the error. Remove the `DATEVALUE()` function from your formula and you should be good to go.

As mentioned in the `DATEVALUE()` function [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5#DATEVALUE)

> DATEVALUE() - Returns a date value for a **date/time** or **text expression**.

Its worth noting and reading the **tips** section of the article given above, out of which, two are related to your issue

## tips

> - If the field referenced in the function is not a valid text or date/time field, the formula field displays #ERROR!
> - When entering a date, surround the date with quotes and use the following format: YYYY-MM-DD, that is, a four-digit year, two-digit month, and two-digit day.